# How can I achieve this style where the subject isn't blurred but bright lights will be light-painted?

Tags: shutter-speed, light, style, shadows, light-painting

I've been going through a company's photographer photos and I could narrow down two styles I'd like to develop and use in my shots, but I cannot figure out how he managed to do it:

It looks like it's using the same principle light writing uses but (also as far as I can tell, he is using a wide-angle lens for most shots), how did he manage to get everything to "rotate" but the subject in the centre of the photo?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Hi Pato and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a question and answer site, not a free-form discussion forum, so it really works best if you split separate questions in to actually separate questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mattdm, will do! (I don't know if I should be ashamed because of you telling me this but I am certainly *not* new to SE)

Comment: No problem. Also, I think we already have the first part of your question answered — does http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37621/how-can-i-create-light-trails-without-a-blurry-subject cover it?

Comment: Please read the following link regarding "How do I get this effect" questions.  http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: @mattdm Yes it does!

Comment: @mattdm should I split this question and then wait for you to reference that question as the answer to the just splitted question (oh god my brain)

Comment: In the case I'd suggest just editing this one to only cover the *other* part. And then we'll delete all this comment mess. :)

Comment: @mattdm splitted style 2 to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/style-with-dim-background-warmer-tones-and-subject-being-almost-the-only-light , thanks!

Comment: This also might be an interesting read: http://neilvn.com/tangents/first-curtain-sync-vs-rear-curtain-sync/

Comment: more possible duplicate questions: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38653/how-does-one-do-light-painting-with-in-focus-subject-maybe-a-composite http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/what-is-the-blurred-light-effect-in-this-portrait http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46086/how-can-i-capture-blurry-movement-and-freeze-a-subject-in-the-same-photograph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Style 1 looks like it's taken with a flash, but exposed for about 1-2 seconds assuming no flash (well probably -2 EV). The flash is set to fire at the start (or end) of the exposure, and the photographer then rotates the camera (around the axis of the lens) over the ~1 second exposure time. A clear image comes from the flash exposing it, and anything especially bright gets smeared in a circle.

I'd suggest setting up your camera in Manual mode, 1 second shutter, and appropriate aperture + ISO to under-expose the scene. Then use your camera's auto flash metering to let it expose the subject clearly. You may want to start rotating the camera *before* you take the image, so it's rotating at a fairly constant pace through the entire shot. On some point-and-shoot cameras this could be achieved with the "night portrait" mode (flash + exposed for scene).

Style 2 looks just looks like a normal flash-lit photo taken in a fairly large room. Set your camera to Manual mode, about 4 EV below the correct exposure for the room, and let the flash auto metering light the subject appropriately.

In both cases they're likely using a diffused flash pointed directly at the subjects, and probably set to underexpose a little. Perhaps using RAW and recovering highlights a little too, as there seems to be only a little "shiny white forehead syndrome".

Finally, they've applied a little warming effect to Style 2 (and perhaps adjusted colours in the others, but the coloured room lighting might be doing that all on its own). You can do this by sliding the white-balance sliders a little towards yellow (and maybe slightly magenta) or adding some kind of standard effect/filter.

Comment: flash could be at the beginning or end, but Pato it might be worth checking out "rear curtain sync" for more on the subject

Comment: @MikeW Is 'rear curtain' the same as 'second curtain'? I'm sure I've read it as second curtain in a photography book before.

Comment: @BBking sounds likely. It means firing when the second/rear curtain is about to close, rather than just after the first has opened.

Comment: @BBking Yes, rear and second curtain are the same.

Comment: much obliged everyone!